# How do you use gsub to remove ¬ character?

Tags: string, url, encoding, lua, gsub

I've tried using `gsub` to remove a `¬` character from a URL, as it shouldn't be there but has been added by a client's server.

Is there a way to remove it? I tried this:

```
s = string.gsub(s, "¬", "")
```

but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Here is the whole code block:

```lua
if link then
    function urlencode(s)
        s = string.gsub(s, "([{}&=+%c])", 
            function(c)
                return string.format("%%%02X", string.byte(c))
            end
        )
        s = string.gsub(s, " ", "+")
        s = string.gsub(s, "¬", "")
        return s
    end

    print(urlencode(link))
    local url = urlencode(link)
    system.openURL(url)
end
```

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://codepad.org/HDXkDkwm

Comment: It works for me as well ,using the [Lua:demo](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) for test:

Comment: I've just checked and if I print the gsubbed string it looks fine, however if I try to use system.openURL in Corona it still has the ¬ character. Must be a Corona problem so I'll ask on their forums.
Does anyone know what the ¬ character is called btw?

Comment: @TheBestBigAl Can you paste the entire code regarding this URL? It might just be a small variable score problem.

Comment: Edited with the code block.

Comment: Can you include the original string and the string you get back? It works for me with `'http://foo.com/more¬less'`.

Comment: It works even then: http://codepad.org/xCexto6e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it could be an encoding mismatch.

That `¬` character in UTF-8 is encoded as `\xC2\xAC` (`\194\172` in decimal). Moreover Lua string library is not code-point aware, it only processes bytes, thus the `"¬"` Lua string literal may be represented differently in the encoding in which the script is stored (on my Windows machine, with code page 1252, it is a simple `\xAC`).  Therefore when the `gsub` function is fed the URL, the byte sequence representing the literal could not match the `\xAC\xC2` in the URL.

Try to see if changing the line:

```
s = string.gsub(s, "¬", "")
```

to:

```
s = string.gsub(s, "\194\172", "")
```

makes any difference.

**Note:** The ¬ symbol is known in [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/#symbols) as the [**"not sign"**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) or also as **"angled dash"** (Unicode code point U+00AC). The corresponding HTML entity is `&not;` or `&#172;`. It is commonly used in math as the **"logical not"** operator (it is the equivalent for mathematicians of the C `!` operator or Lua `not` operator).